# Why doesn't my clear button/hovering work after changing color?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a sketch hover app. When the cursor hovers over a grid square the square fills with the color currently picked and when you hover over it again the color gets removed.

Initialy everything seems to be working. I can hover over a square to apply a `red color` and re-hover to remove it or press the `clear button` to clear everything. But when i change the color to e.g. `green`, i can't remove the color anymore by hovering and the `clear button` doesn't work. Why is this happening?

http://codepen.io/cgonen/full/zNQMMY/  <= Link to hover app.

```js
$(function () {
    
    grid()
    clear()
    createGrid()
    hover()
    colorpick()
})


function createGrid(size) {
        $('.grid').empty()
        size = 16;
        width = 600 / size;
        for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                $('.grid').append('<div class="vlak"></div>')
            }
        }
            $('.vlak').css("width", width)
            $('.vlak').css("height", width)
        
    } // end


function grid() {
    $('input').on('change', function() {
        size = $('input').val();

        createGrid(size)
    })
}

function hover(c) {
    $('.vlak').on('mouseenter', function(){

        
        console.log(c)
        if($(this).hasClass('color')) {
            $(this).removeClass('color')
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('color');
            $('.color').css('background-color', c)
        }

    })
}

function colorpick() {
    $('select').on('change', function(){
        var c = $(this).val()
        $('.vlak').off()
        hover(c)
    })
}

function clear() {
    $('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.vlak').removeClass('color')
    })
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit; }

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both; }

.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto; }

.grid {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 1px solid black; }

.vlak {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black; }

.color {
  background-color: red; }

.black {
  background-color: black; }

.red {
  background-color: red; }

.blue {
  background-color: blue; }

.pink {
  background-color: pink; }

.green {
  background-color: green; }

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width", initiat-scale="1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
</head>
    
<body>
    
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="header">
            <h1>HoverMatic</h1>
            <p>General description placeholder</p>
            <input type="number" value="16" placeholder="grid size">
            <select name="colors" id="">
                <option value="black">black</option>
                <option value="blue">blue</option>
                <option value="green">green</option>
                <option value="pink">pink</option>
                <option value="red">red</option>
                <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
            </select>
            <button>clear grid</button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: please show the relevant code in the question

Comment: Had a codepen but added the code snippet aswell now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to clear the style backgound try this

```
    function clear() {
       $('button').on('click', function(){
          $('.vlak').removeClass('color')
          $('.vlak').css({'background-color':'inherit'})  
       })
    }
```

Comment: Hmm.. what do you mean with clear style background? This works for the clear button part, but i don't understand why $('.vlak').css({'background-color':'inherit'} does the trick.

Comment: You edit your issue, your first issue was how to remove the color when you change the color and press the clear button.

Comment: Yeah i'm sorry for that, choose a bad title. Edited to better fit my question. The 'why' part is important to learn.

Comment: Well, I don´t understand at all your code, but I inspect the DOM for watch how hover fills the color in the grid, and I saw when user clicks on the clear button you remove the class but the color style stills present, so the solution is to clear this property.

Comment: hmm.. having another look. New to coding, kinda lost track.. :P.

Answer (score 1):

@jorges answer fixes one part of the issue. you also need to add:

`$(this).css({'background-color': 'inherit'})`

in your hover function after `$(this).removeClass('color')`.

and then replace line 44 with:
`$('.color').css({'background-color': c})`